# How to replace an AC/AC power that has 2 outputs

Tags: power-supply, ac

Hi the power adapter for my mixer broke, and I need a new one (Alesis MultiMix 16 USB 2.0). However they don't make them anymore, so I'm looking for an alternate solution. It has two 18V outputs that go into the mixer. So I was wonder if it's possible to hook up two separate power adapters to it to make it work, or find 1 power adapter and split it. However, I don't know what the necessary specs would be to make this work. Here is a picture of the broken power adapter's label.

What would the circuit diagram look like for hooking up two supplies to a three prong adapter?

[image]

Here is what the end that plugs into the mixer looks like:

[image]

Comment: Look at the questions on replacing power supplies on this site for how to match the specs. Short answer is you could replace this with two supplies and some hacking

Comment: I'm going to change the question up so its not a repair question.

Comment: I'm going to make an educated guess here and say that your AC/AC adapter is probably a center-tapped 36V transformer. Although replacing that with 2 separate power supplies is probably possible, it might get tricky.

Answer (score 0):

- separate secondary windings offers "some" isolation of crosstalk from dynamic load regulation , so you can also use independent supplies or integral XFMR with shared common or center tap.

However a common electrical connection is needed, and out of phase reduces radiated CM hum by "some" cancellation. i.e. so I might wire outputs like center tap. But depending on dynamic loads, it may not make any difference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbWiGJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would 2 of these work? https://goo.gl/cWZMUc

Comment: go same or bigger, not smaller http://www.jameco.com/z/AFU180200-18VAC-2A-AC-to-AC-Wall-Adapter-Power-Supply_2179622.html

Comment: I'd add a 1A fuse+fuseholder on the AC input, because the original DID fail, and input power protection that's replaceable would be good.