# How to tell the polarity of a power adapter's wires

Tags: power-supply, polarity

I purchased a power adapter so that I could put a different plug on it, but when I cut the wire and stripped it, it didn't have a colored jacket on it. The brick does not have a diagram on it, so I have no way of knowing which is positive, and which is negative.

I have a multimeter, and set it to  AC Voltage, and touched the red lead to one wire, and the black to the other. it was a positive voltage reading. I switched the leads and wires, and I got a postive voltage again. This is the power adapter I used:

[Power Adapter](http://www.jameco.com/z/ADU180100-AC-to-AC-Wall-Adapter-Transformer-18-Volt-1000mA-Black-Straight-2-1mm-Female-Plug_121216.html)

This is the multimeter I'm using:

[Multi-Meter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015X6LN2Y)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This adapter is just a fused transformer in a box. It gives an isolated ac voltage output. There is no polarity in such a system.  One wire will have a sinusoidally varying voltage around the other, sometimes positive, sometimes negative. Therefore you may connect the wires either way.

If you want a dc output, with one wire having a constantly positive voltage above the other, you bought the wrong item.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm trying to figure out how to adapt it work for this, as what I'm trying to do here is a continuation of this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296003/how-to-replace-an-ac-ac-power-that-has-2-outputs/296015?noredirect=1#comment680845_296015